# Creating an n tiered application

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture, soa

I am researching architecture for a project that will be started next year. It is mainly a c# web app, but there will be a service layer so that it can talk to our facebook/iphone app. There are a few long running processes, which means that I will be creating a windows process that can handle those.

I’m thinking of putting the entire app in the windows service instead of just the long running processes.

Asp -> wcf -> bll
Vs
Asp -> bll

I know this will be more scalable. But it is probably overkill  as everything will be running on the same box, even the database. This could change down the road if the server can’t handle the traffic like marketing says it will.

I don’t have access to production hardware, just my crappy testing box and my local machine.

Has anyone decided to go down this route?

But mostly, what is the best way to test both methods to get some metrics?

Comment: I think im just trying to find out what is the best way to figure out how expencive wcf -> service layer calls are in a production environment without having to create the entire app.

Answer (score 0):

Asp->bll can be as much scalable if you consider web farms. From performance perspective, its depends upon service/bll contract - for chunky kind of contract, many times, time to execute the call can be sufficiently large compared to out of proc call (involved in invoking service layer) - so no large impact of performance. But if interface is chatty and call execution are shorter then having service layer can really hurt but then as long as you can meet your SLAs (response time vs number of users), it shouldn't matter.

As prod environment is going to be a single box initially, you can use your dev box or testing box for coming up with metrics. As said, you need to check performance for both short running methods and long (relative) running methods and then decide based on what will be the kind of methods that will be mostly called, is performance hit you get for these kind of methods is ok etc.